# Email Sending .NET Core

Tags: email, asp.net-core

I just want to have a function, which will be sending mail to different people.

I have written a Email Service, just like this:

```
 public void SendEMail(EMail mail)
    {
        var body = JObject.FromObject(settings);
        body.Merge(JObject.FromObject(mail));

        GlobalTelemetry.TrackDependency("E-Mail Service", "Send", () =>
        {
            var result = AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => httpClient.PostAsync(azureFunctionUrl,
                new StringContent(body.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")));
            if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    $"E-Mail Service failed to send mails. Http Status {result.StatusCode}. Please check if the Url '{azureFunctionUrl}' is correct. Env: {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}");
            }
        });
    }
```

and by every other functions, which want to use this mail service, do just like this:

```
 SendMail = mail =>
        {
            var fireAndForgetTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    eMailService.SendEMail(mail);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.Fatal(e, $"Fail to send  E-Mail to: '{mail.To}'");
                }
            });
        };
```

it does work, but `fireAndForgetTask` is not used, I have no idea how to do it better.
Is it necessary to write a Email Job???

Some better suggestion is welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar issue in my app for sending a password reset email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35175960/net-core-alternative-to-threadpool-queueuserworkitem), I did not want the delay of waiting for the email to send because if a hacker is trying to find out if an account exists for an email address the delay could indicate that the account does exist. So I wanted to fire and forget the email with no delay.

So I implemented a simple extension method named forget like this in a separate static class [based on this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629951/suppressing-warning-cs4014-because-this-call-is-not-awaited-execution-of-the):

```
public static void Forget(this Task task)
{

}
```

and then I send my email async and use that .Forget extension to not wait for it like this:

```
emailSender.SendPasswordResetEmailAsync(
Site,
model.Email,
sr["Reset Password"],
resetUrl).Forget();
```

note that I am not using "await" when I call this async method and the .Forget gets rid of the warning that would otherwise appear in Visual Studio when calling an async method without the await keyword